# How to fix the wrong total in table visualization in power BI?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, dax, data-analysis, powerquery

I have a measure name Y_Test, where Y_Test is:

```
Y_Test = 
VAR Y = SUM(Sheet1[C2])
var result = IF(MAX(Sheet1[C1]) = "A", Y, IF(((MAX(Sheet1[C1])) = "B" || (MAX(Sheet1[C1]) = "C")),  -1 * Y))
Return result
```

I'm getting the total as -16, shouldn't it be 8?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Output]

[image: Data Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative option, you can try an iterator, in this case, `SUMX`.

The operation would be run for each instance of `'Table'[C1]`, so you need to be careful if the number of rows for the unique values of `C1` is too big.

### Measure

```
Y_TEST =
SUMX (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[C1] ),
    IF ( [C1] = "A", 1, IF ( [C1] IN { "B", "C" }, -1 ) )
        * CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[C2] ) )
)
```

### Table

| C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | a |
| B | 2 | b |
| C | 3 | b |
| D | 2 | d |
| A | 1 | a |
| B | 3 | b |
| C | 4 | C |
| D | 2 | d |
| A | 2 | d |

Answer (score 1):

Follow this below steps-

**Step-1:** Create a new **calculated column** as below-

```
new_c2 = 
IF(
    Sheet1[C1] = "A",
    Sheet1[C2],
    IF(
        Sheet1[C1] = "B" || Sheet1[C1] = "C",
        Sheet1[C2] * -1
    )    
)
```

**Step-2:** Now create the **Measure** as below-

```
Y_Test = SUM(Sheet1[new_c2])
```

Output-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula instead:

```
    CALCULATE (
           SUM ( Sheet1[C2] ),
           KEEPFILTERS ( Sheet1[C1] = "A" )
          ) -
   CALCULATE (
          SUM ( Sheet1[C2] ),
          KEEPFILTERS ( Sheet1[C1] IN { "B", "C" } )
          )
```